# 'on the globe' or 'across the globe'?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence-structure

I am having trouble understanding the mistake in the following sentence.

> *Our country is blessed with more educated people than any other country, and we have arguably most number of graduates on the globe.*

Which of the following is correct?

> a) we arguably have most number of graduates on the globe.
>   b) we have arguably most number of graduates across the globe.
>   c) The original statement

Also is there a rule that states where should ***'arguably'*** should be kept in a sentence?

Comment: You'll need the definite article, and *most number* is not idiomatic.  Use either *the most* or *the greatest number*.

Answer (score 1):

The noun "globe"(our planet) can take prepositions *across*, *all over* and *around/round*. I think that if it means a sphere on which a map is represented, there may be something *on* it.

I'd use "the highest/biggest/greatest number" instead of "most number" though.

As for the adverb *arguably*, to me, it's position in variant B seems to be preferable to that in the original sentence.

Although if you paraphrase the sentence using a literal meaning of "arguably", it may read without any change of the idea:

> ... and we have, as can be shown by argument, the most number of
>   graduates across the globe.
>
> ... and as can be shown by argument, we have the most number of graduates
>   across the globe.

Answer (score 0):

It should be 'across' the globe, not 'on' the globe.  If you are 'on' a globe you are on just ONE spot, but if you go 'across' a globe, now you are talking about many countries.  I would say "we arguably have" not "have arguably".  Should be "the highest number" of graduates.  I'm not crazy about the entire sentence though.  I would either break it into two sentences as two distinct thoughts OR state your country is 'blessed" BECAUSE you have the highest number of graduates. Depends upon what your point is.

Answer (score 0):

As a business and copy writer for more than 25 years, my professional opinion is thart neither statement is correct because the second half of the sentence - "we have arguably most number of graduates" - lacks a grammatically critical word in order for the sentence to make any sense.

Get rid of the word globe, entirely.  Nobody uses the word because it's not referential.  In the first half of the sentence, the second use of the word "country" is ubiquitous and unnecessary.  It makes the sentence very clunky.

Try this - grammatically correct and resolves your dilemma -

Our country is blessed with more educated people than any other because we have arguably the most number of graduates in the world.